# Can't get convertRect: fromView to work

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, coordinates, frame

Inside my `viewController` I have this `tableView` with custom cells.
On my `cellForRow:atIndexPath:` method I'd like to access the location (`rect`), according to my **viewController's** **coordinate system**, of a UIButton that is displayed inside a specific cell.
This is how I was thought it would work:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
               cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellId") as? MyCell
    if cell != nil {

        cell = MyCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    }

    let convertedFrame = view.convertRect(cell!.myButton.Frame, fromView: cell)

    return cell!
}
```

It just gives me the current frame of the button in its own coordinate system `(0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 44.0)`

Any clues on the correct usage of that method?

Comment: Why are you doing this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? The cell isn't even added to the table yet.

Comment: Hmm. That makes sense. That's probably a bad place for doing this.

Comment: Not only it makes sense, but it also did the trick.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a matter of calling it before the cell were actually placed in the view hierarchy. Thanks to **rmaddy** for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
let convertedFrame = view.convertRect(cell!.myButton.Frame, fromView: cell)
```

to

```
let convertedFrame = view.convert(cell!.myButton.Frame, fromView: cell)
```